# In supersized jquery how to pass bunch of images dynmically by using java

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

am implementing supersized j query with jsp's The problem is how to send a bunch of images into jquery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    $(function(){

        $.fn.supersized.options = {
            <% String str="Hello World"; %>
            <%System.out.println("am from function1");%>
            startwidth: $("#name").val(),  
            startheight: 480,
            vertical_center: 1,
            slideshow: 1,
            navigation: 1,
            thumbnail_navigation: 1,
            transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
            pause_hover: 0,
            slide_counter: 1,
            slide_captions: 1,
            slide_interval: 3000,
            slides :  [ {image : '/Email/slides/tower.jpg', title : 'City Clock Tower', url : 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/wumbus/4582735030/in/set-72157623876357531/'},
                {image : '/Email/slides/fence.jpg', title : 'Canal Park Fence', url : 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/wumbus/4582735030/sizes/l/in/set-72157623876357531/'},  
                {image : '/Email/slides/tracks.jpg', title : 'Old Train Tracks', url : 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/wumbus/4582733542/in/set-72157623876357531/'},
                {image : '/Email/slides/001.jpg', title : 'Old1 Train Tracks', url : 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/wumbus/4582733542/in/set-72157623876357531/'} ]


        };
        $('#supersized').supersized(); 
    });
</script>
```

In the above script 
slides:[{image:'/Email/slides/tower.jpg'}{}...  ] array statically am able to adding images.
but dynamically how to pass a n number of images by using java

.

If anybody knows answer me i appreciate him.

Answer (score 0):

1 Put Collection of images into request in you servlet/controller:

```
Collection<String> images = ... ; // loading from your source

request.setAttribute("images", images);
```

2 In jsp use JSTL to loop:

```
<c:forEach var="image" items=${images}>
    <c:out value="${image}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Thats all.